# How to access a column value in models in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want access a value of column "type" in below model function but the value of "$this" is null.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class DealerOrderItem extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    use SoftDeletes;


    public function Item()
    {
        if ($this->type == 'PackToPack')
            return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PackToPack', 'id', 'item_id');
        elseif ($this->type == 'QcItem')
            return $this->hasOne('App\Models\QcItem', 'id', 'item_id');

    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->columnName`, `public function Item()` its a relation method, i dont understand what do u need

Comment: I want to access a column value to define conditional relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you could defaine two different relations
 1.PackToPack

2.QcItem
and check the condition when you call the relation function

OR>

you may set a getter as type and you may access it with $this->item

i am skeptical about 2nd method it might not work, let me know if it did

Comment: please upvote it if it worked for you, i would be encouraged to answer more

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relationship to be defined correctly, you would need:

```
$dealerOrderItem->item->name
```

`$dealerOrderItem` being an instance of that model which has been previously loaded, and '`name`' being the name of the column you want to view.

If you have specific code which is not working after trying this, please share that code as well as the model and db structure for the items table.

Comment: I have elobrated my question

Comment: You need to show the full picture. What does the database look like? How are you loading the record? What makes you think '$this' is null, how are you testing that understanding?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask